# org.springframework.experimental:spring-aot-maven-plugin:jar:0.9.2 was not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I added the dependency and plugins using this documentation-
https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

I also tried-
`mvn clean install`
.But I keep getting this error-
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add this repository . Because `spring-aot-maven-plugin`  plugin available in this repository `https://repo.spring.io/release`

```
<repositories>
        
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Local Nexus</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

i have tried this plugin with above repository  :

```
<groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
```

and it is working fine..

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer from hdha, for plugins from different repositories, you can add pluginRepsoitories tag to mention the url to use for certain plugins.

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Local Nexus</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do u try to change the version to 0.9.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

The same error happened to me, finally, after 1 hour I noticed that if you want to work with Spring Native

```
 <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <repackage.classifier />
    <spring-native.version>0.12.1</spring-native.version>
  </properties>
...

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
 </dependency>

and then...

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
  <executions>...
```

You have to add the two answers indicated here, so you look for them in this repo and not in maven central

```
 <pluginRepositories>
     <pluginRepository>
       <id>snapshots</id>
       <name>Nexus Local</name>
       <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
     </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>

   <repositories>
     <repository>
       <id>spring-release</id>
       <name>Spring release</name>
       <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
       <snapshot>
         <enabled>false</enabled>
       </snapshot>
     </repository>
   </repositories>

</project>
```